# NameError in Posts#show in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm receiving this error on my Rails application
"undefined local variable or method `topic' for #<#:someNum>"

```
 <%= form_for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% if comment.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__92596123__625140068'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:30:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb__385866763__625570018'
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix?

Comment: Need more information to answer the question. Have a look at this this documentation .. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form is in a partial.

If this form is part of an iterator, or if the local variable is only defined on the main posts/show.html, you need to pass the local variable to the form partial

```
<%= render 'form', topic: topic %>
```

Most likely, given your setup, you'll have to include it for all 3 local variables.

```
<%= render 'form', topic: topic, post: post, comment: comment %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! this is what i have for the partial

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
```